# Android: getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true); not working

Tags: android, listview

The method setTextFilterEnabled(true) gives the wrong result. on inputing.. I don't know what is the problem.(It gives the wrong search result).

Here is the complete code of my demo application

```
public class AndroidCustomListActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names)));
       getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

   private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        String[] items=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
        String[] items1=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.address);


        ImageView iv=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv1=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        tv.setText(items[position]);

        if(items[position].equals("Tuhin Bhatt"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.tuhin);
            tv1.setText(items1[position]);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("Rikhil Jain"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ronaldo);
            tv1.setText(items1[position]);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("David Beckham"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.davidbeckham);
            tv1.setText(items1[position]);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("Luis Figo"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.luisfigo);
            tv1.setText(items1[position]);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("David Silva"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.davidsilva);
            tv1.setText(items1[position]);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("Wayne Rooney"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.waynerooney);
            tv1.setText(items1[position]);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("Iker Casillas"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ikercasillas);
            tv1.setText(items1[position]);
        }


        return row;
    }



}
}
```

Everything else is working properly. The code runs perfectly except this Problem....
I know i posted a very long code.. but i thought it might help to pinpoint the problem